# Highcharts multiple stacked columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am working with the following demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-stacked-percent/

The problem is that I want to have five columns with five pieces of unrelated data. Imagine the following situation:

I want five bars

The first bar is `data [50, 50, 50] (A, B, C)`

The second bar is a completely separate `dataset: [40, 50, 60] (D, E, F)`

The third bar is another separate `dataset: [50, 50, 50, 45, 50, 60] (G, H, I, J, K L)`

Fourth.. fifth.. etc.

So these bars are completely unrelated with the data inside them, but are on the same graph.

Many thanks.

p.s. My apologies, but as I have tried so many variations of mixing series / data / different types / multiple axis  that writing what solutions I have tried up until now will only create confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are: http://jsfiddle.net/L257S/
For each unrelated point you need to set separate series. Then each series will contain only one point with specified `[x, y]` point object, to determine by x-value which category is correct. Code example:

```
        series: [{
            name: 'John',
            data: [[0,5]] //first category
        }, {
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [[0,2]]
        }, {
            name: 'Joe',
            data: [[0,3]]
        },{
            name: 'John1',
            data: [[1,5]] //second category
        }, {
            name: 'Jane1',
            data: [[1,2]]
        }, {
            name: 'Joe1',
            data: [[1,3]]
        },{
            name: 'John2',
            data: [[2,5]] //third category
        }, {
            name: 'Jane2',
            data: [[2,2]]
        }, {
            name: 'Joe2',
            data: [[2,3]]
        }]
```

Comment: Excellent!  At first it didn't seem like what I was looking for but it solves our problem perfectly!  Thank you